# check parameter is valid or not in jsp

Tags: java, jsp, vxml

I just want to check that the parameter passed to the jsp are null or not using httpcontext  so how i can able to do that

```
case_yr = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("case_yr"));
sub_type_int =Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("sub_type_int"));
String case_num = request.getParameter("case_num");
String lang_mode = request.getParameter("lang_mode");
String mobile_no = request.getParameter("caller_id");
String dialled_id = request.getParameter("dialled_id");
```

i want to above values are valid or not I am submitting value from xml page to jsp page and getting value in jsp using `request.getparameter()`

so pleaase tell how to check values are null or not and there is no sevlet only vxml page and jsp page

Comment: what do you mean "valid"?? .. do you mean to test if request attributes are null ?

Answer (score 1):

if you wanna check if the request attributes are `null`,just check if they are `null` this way

```
String case_num = request.getParameter("case_num");
if(case_num!=null){
    //do your logic
 }
 else {
  System.out.println("case_num is null");
  }
 int number ;
String num = request.getParameter(num);
 if(num!=null){
     number = Integer.parseInt(num);
   }
 else {
  System.out.println("case_num is null");
  }
```

Comment: if there are int in place of string then how to do that

Comment: I have already done that but i want to do that at httpcontext level so how to do that

Answer (score 0):

Use JSTL

```
<c:if test="${not empty case_num}">
    case_num is NOT empty or null.
</c:if>
```